# Calling different function on error. Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've got a little script that will check for new files in a folder, and it will print all of the PDF files. Whenever the print fails, the `%errorlevel%` variable will go up to 1. I'm trying to use an if statement with goto and labels to get it to work but I can't figure out what is going on.

The script is:

```
:printfile
echo printing %1
set fname=%1
set fullFname="print\STW_Print\STW_Printer_TEST\%fname:~1%
echo ERLVL: %errorlevel%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -silent -print-to "\\s8011\OPS_2055_IS" %
echo ERLVL: %errorlevel%
set logFilename=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error
echo Moving %fname% to printed
move %fullFname% STW_printed
echo %time% %1 Printed on STWTEST and Moved>> Printlogs\TEST-%logFilename%-log.txt
goto eof
:error
echo Moving %fname% to failed
move %fullFname% STW_failed
echo %time% %1 Failed on STWTEST and Moved>> Printlogs\TEST-%logFilename%-log.txt
GOTO eof

:eof
```

The line that calls the script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir print\STW_Print\STW_Printer_TEST\*.pdf /b') do (call :printfile "%%i")
```

And my output:

```
printing "BADTEST (2) - Copy.pdf"
ERLVL: 0
ERLVL: 1
Moving "BADTEST (2) - Copy.pdf" to printed
    1 file(s) moved.
printing "BADTEST (2).pdf"
ERLVL: 0
ERLVL: 1
Moving "BADTEST (2).pdf" to printed
    1 file(s) moved.
printing "BADTEST (3) - Copy.pdf"
ERLVL: 0
ERLVL: 1
Moving "BADTEST (3) - Copy.pdf" to printed
    1 file(s) moved.
```

I can't figure out why it's not moving to failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you check errorlevel after doing the SET command... which clears errorlevel. Move your 'set logfilename...' line farther up.  Also, when using errolevel you can just do

```
if errorlevel 1 goto :error
```